# PySpark - Check from a list of values are present in any of the columns in a Dataframe

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a Dataframe 'DF' with 200 columns and around 500 million records.
I have another list of values as 'l'.
I want to check, for each of the values in the list l, each of the value is present in which column in my Dataframe DF.

For example,

```
l = [101,102,103,104,105]
```

DF =

```
col1,col2,col3

1,2,101

2,3,102

3,103,4

4,104,5

105,5,6

6,105,7
```

My output should be as below:

```
101,col3

102,col3

103,col2

104,col2

105,col1

105,col2
```

Answer (score 2):

Unpivot the dataframe using `stack`, and then filter the dataframe using `isin`:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

l = [101,102,103,104,105]

df2 = df.selectExpr("""
    stack(3, col1, 'col1', col2, 'col2', col3, 'col3') as (val, col)
""").filter(
    F.col('val').isin(l)
)

df2.show()
+---+----+
|val| col|
+---+----+
|101|col3|
|102|col3|
|103|col2|
|104|col2|
|105|col1|
|105|col2|
+---+----+
```

Comment: mck - If I have to find in 200 columns, should I be giving 200 columns in the stack? I don't think so that would be efficient. Could you please suggest a better way?

Comment: You can construct the stack expression using a list comprehension

Answer (score 1):

Another way without unpivoting the data frame :

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F

df1 = df.withColumn(
    "presence_arr",
    F.array(*[
        F.when(F.col(c).isin(l), F.struct(F.lit(c).alias("col"), F.col(c).alias("val")))
        for c in df.columns
    ])) \
    .withColumn("presence_arr", F.expr(f"filter(presence_arr, x -> x is not null)")) \
    .agg(F.collect_set("presence_arr").alias("presence_arr")) \
    .withColumn("presence_arr", F.explode(F.flatten("presence_arr"))) \
    .select("presence_arr.*")

df1.show(truncate=False)

#+----+---+
#|col |val|
#+----+---+
#|col2|105|
#|col3|101|
#|col3|102|
#|col1|105|
#|col2|104|
#|col2|103|
#+----+---+
```

For each row, we check each column if it's present in the list of values, then agg to collect all the arrays, flatten and explode to get the desired output.